# Add to one context and update another context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In here I add some data to database using EF code.When i add using one context it's working.But I need to update another table(another context) using ProductId(productId avaialble in iOdr object.

Here is my code

```
public int AddorUpdateSalesOrder(ref InvoiceHD iOdr)
{
    try
    {
        if (iOdr.InvoiceId != null)
        {
           //context.Entry(iOdr).State = EntityState.Modified;
           context.InvoiceHDs.Add(iOdr);
           //Here I need to update Product context 
           //using ProductId(it's available in iOdr).
           //If ProductId is 1 then I need to 
           //update product tables ProductQuantity coloumn with new value
        }
        else
        {
            context.InvoiceHDs.Add(iOdr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
    return context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have no idea how to do second context.could you please someone give me help for this.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly then you just need to create a new instance of your other context, get back the record you need to update, update that record and SaveChanges on that context.